Repeatedly execute a function for a specific period of time on stm32
I am trying to work with STM32 board and I want a function, to be executed repeatedly for a certain period of time. The code looks something like this.
while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

      for(count = 0; count<1000;count++){
          
          num_display_func(count);
          
         / /HAL_Delay(10);
      }

How to make the function run multiple times, let's say within in a period of 1 sec?
I have tried using while loop yet I cannot wrap my head around.

Use the same principle as yourself, take the current time at the begin of the interval, and repeat until the current time is the sum of the begin and the interval (interval is over).

Further to other comments / answers, you might want to investigate HAL_GetTick().

Seemingly you are updating some output display. Means there is no need to execute a function repeatedly. Executing a function once (periodically) should be more than enough. Any reason why you are looking for multiple time execution of a function?

It is a seven segment display.
So It requires to be updated frequently(perception of vision)?

These kind of "busy-wait" functions should pretty much never be used in professional embedded systems, because such systems are almost always real-time systems with timing deadlines. Busy-delays numerous problems: inaccuracy, wasted CPU capacity, wasted current consumption, prone to optimization mishaps etc etc. But worst of all it stalls the whole program and destroys everything else that needs to be executed in a timely fashion.
The correct way to solve this is to use an on-chip hardware peripheral timer, then either poll the timer flag or set up an interrupt to execute when the timer has elapsed. In case of Cortex M MCUs, the Systick timer is ideal for such purposes.

(I've meant to post a self-answered Q&A about how to write a proper timer HAL at some point. The problem is that all my example code for such is proprietary so I have to write and test an equivalent example on some mainstream MCU. Lets just say that ST doesn't have the slightest clue about what a "HAL" is supposed to be good for, nor do they have any intention of providing the means to port your code away from STM32, which would be the main benefit of a correctly designed HAL.)

Look into the HAL_Delay() function's implementation: it's an empty loop waiting for a certain change of a variable (changed in SysTick interrupt). Copy that loop into your main(), and place the call of your function into that loop.
